# Unable to set path in jaudiotagger

Tags: android, audio, mediastore, android-music-player, jaudiotagger

I'm trying to edit tags of audio files and for that I'm using JaudioTagger. But a problem exists and I can't figure it out.

I'm getting this error:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method toPath()Ljava/nio/file/Path; in class Ljava/io/File; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.io.File' appears in /system/framework/core-oj.jar)`

And my code for getting tags of audio files :

```
            File path = new File(songInfoModel.getData());
            Log.e("Path: ", path.toString());
            try {
                AudioFile f = AudioFileIO.read(path);
                Tag tag = f.getTag();
                String artist = tag.getFirst(FieldKey.ARTIST);
                tag.getFirst(FieldKey.ALBUM);
                tag.getFirst(FieldKey.TITLE);
                tag.getFirst(FieldKey.COMMENT);
                tag.getFirst(FieldKey.YEAR);
                tag.getFirst(FieldKey.TRACK);
                tag.getFirst(FieldKey.DISC_NO);
                tag.getFirst(FieldKey.COMPOSER);
                tag.getFirst(FieldKey.ARTIST_SORT);

                Log.e("Artist: ",artist);
            } catch (CannotReadException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (TagException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ReadOnlyFileException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvalidAudioFrameException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: this is a known problem with jaudiotagger. Check out this thread for more details. The latest version of android api27 now has the necessary files.

https://bitbucket.org/ijabz/jaudiotagger/issues/149/some-nio-classes-are-unavailable-while

Comment: Actually I resolved it by downgrading to the previous version. Now it works fine. Thank you

Comment: Can you please post the version you now use?

Comment: Yeah sure, I use 2.2.3.

Comment: Theo, I have a question actually, wonder if you could help me with it? It's related to expandable recyclerview.

Comment: I will try. Contact me by email though. email address can be found on http://www.theo.klinkweb.nl/

Comment: okay. Actually I have posted the question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48250204/how-to-create-multiple-views-in-parent-viewholderexpandable-recyclerview